# How to customize DotNetNuke "Please update your profile" page depending on user role?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I am looking after a  DNN website that is used by 2 distinct types of users. Each type requires users to enter different bits of personal information.

At the moment, when a new user logs in they're asked to enter additional information, which is just a set of standard DNN profile definition fields. My question is how do I get it to show different fields depending on what role the user is on?

I'd prefer a solution that would not require me to modify any DNN source code as to not affect future upgrades. The site is currently on DNN version 5.06.

Comment: You might check to see if dynamic registration from DataSprings will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to customize login module.According to your requirement you need to create your own module where you can set flag if it is first login force user to update the profile based upon role and update the flag so next onward no need to force user.

or

You can try any built module if it is available to your requirement.